# ANDROID_LOOP = true -- how to avoid MediaPlayer looping audios with this metadata tag

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to play device ringtones with MediaPlayer yet it seems when the metadata tag

```
ANDROID_LOOP = true
```

is set MediaPlayer is ignoring the call of the method *setLooping*

```
mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
```

and loops the audio in any case. Also the onCompletionListener method is not called.

I noticed that even audio apps like ES Media Player loop audios with this tag set to true regardless if looping is enabled or not.

So my question is if I can

- make MediaPlayer ignoring this tag
- temporary modify the tag so that MediaPlayer does not loop the audio

This question arose around ringtones yet it is of course not ringtone specific. Funnily the tutorials I found on how to play ringtones all set mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true); so that they dont have to handle this problem it seems ...

Thanks

[image]

Comment: FWIW, even the stock media selector (when selecting ringtones from the Android settings activity) seems to loop the ringtones. Doesn't seem to be a way to ignore the metadata tag, other than somehow editing it (no idea how to go about that on the phone).

Comment: More info: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1314
Doesn't seem like they're inclined to change anything about this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Might not be a satisfactory answer, but it seems the engineers are not inclined to change the behavior of `MediaPlayer` and the metadata tag `ANDROID_LOOP=true` for ogg files. See issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1314

As for temporarily modifying the tag, I don't know how you could go about doing that.

I haven't tested it but I believe other sound formats don't exhibit this behavior (e.g. mp3 or wav). Perhaps you could convert the ogg files to a different format and keep them as temp data (might help with this: [Java - Convert ogg to mp3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883659/java-convert-ogg-to-mp3)) This of course seems like a lot of overhead to play back some files, but at least they're usually small files.